# Why so many jars in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Ours is a Web based Application in which we are using Log4J for logging purposes .
The version we are using is log4j1.2.16

We want to migrate to Log4J2 as we need introduced some asynchronous logging also in our Application currently .

When downloaded apache-log4j-2.0-beta7-bin found 31 jars in it .
Please tell me why so many jars present , do we need all of them ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all of them (in fact, some of them are mutually exclusive).
You will need at least the API and CORE jars. The Async Loggers may be separated out into another jar in a future release.

Depending on how you want to separate logging for individual web applications, you may also need the WEB jar. More details on logging separation are here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html
If the documentation is insufficient please give a shout to the log4j-users mailing list so it can be improved.

Log4j-2 is broken up into modules to help users control the dependencies. This is especially useful for people using Maven or building OSGi apps. The log4j developer community is divided on the issue of whether there should be a single "log4j-all" jar. Your feedback on the log4j-users or dev mailing lists could make a difference.